# How to read csv file and render UI?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have a simple shiny app and when I press a button a .csv file is saved in the directory where the file app.R is.
I want to be able to read this csv file and render the information in a table on my shiny app.

This is a similiar example about what I would like to do

```
df <- data.frame(no =c(1:3),money=c(9999:10001),penalty=c(999:1001))


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),actionButton("sort","Do Sorting")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents"),tableOutput("sortedcontents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  rawInputData = reactive({
    rawData = input$file1
    
    
    if(!is.null(rawData)) {
      data = read.csv(rawData$datapath);
    } else {
      return(NULL);
    }
    
  });
  
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    newData = rawInputData()  
    if(is.null(newData))
      return();
    newData;
  })
  
  sorting = reactive({
    if(input$sort){
      newData = rawInputData()
      newData$moneysort <- ifelse(newData$money >=10000, 1, 0)
      newData$penaltysort <- ifelse(newData$penalty >=1000, 1, 0)
    }
    newData
    
  })
  output$sortedcontents <- renderTable({
    newData = sorting()  
    if(is.null(newData))
      return();
    newData;
  })
  
}


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Instead to have the opportunity to choose the file with a fileInpunt() I would like to avoid this step and automatically check a specific directory to look for the csv called "myData.csv" and render this csv in a table.

Comment: Have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - the best way to get help here is to post example data, and expected output, along with an explanation of your problem. The description you've given is a little hard to follow without a concrete example. When possible, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just read a csv file `df <- read.csv('filename.csv')` and render it in `renderTable()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of just reading data from local directory and rendering in shiny.

```r
library(shiny)

write.csv(iris, 'iris.csv')
df = read.csv('iris.csv')

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             tableOutput('iris_table')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$iris_table <- renderTable(df)
  }
)
```

This example uses a slight modification from [this shiny TableOutput reference](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.12.1/tableOutput.html).